# Author Page User id in functions.php for non login user

Tags: functions, author, id

I would like to access author **id** when a visitor come to author page?  when I am coding in **author.php** file, I could print author id like below

```
$q_obj = get_queried_object();
$user_id = (int) $q_obj->data->ID;
```

But, if I would like to get **user id** functions.php, How should I print?

```
function zb_user_analyze() {
    // I would like to access user id here
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'zb_user_analyze');
```

Note: I only want to access author page **user id** for nonlogin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_loaded hook runs before Wordpress has setup postdata so you won't be able to get there the information you need.

The earliest hook you can use to have that information should be [wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp).

You can use [is_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) to check if you're on an author page and [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) to check if the user is logged in:

```
function zb_user_analyze() {
    if( is_author() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $author_id = get_query_var( 'author' );
        // do something
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'zb_user_analyze');
```

Comment: Did this helped?